# how to programatically search/traverse an object in chrome dev tools watch to find a value?

Tags: javascript

I have a watch set in my Chrome Dev Tools.  The watch value is an object and it's fairly large. I'm somewhat unfamiliar with the object and I'm looking for the existence of a particular value within the object tree.

If I can identify the element/attribute with the expected value then this will give me a good hook that I can use for further debugging and solution implementation. Are you aware of any type of js lib or function that I can use to accomplish this? For example, I'd like to add a watch like:

```
ObjectSearcher.Search('app.min.css')
```

This would then search the object for instances of that value and then return a collapsed definition of the object with references to that search value.

Comment: So your object has a key named "app.min.css" and you want that key:value?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Watches observe a value of a property, not the output of a function call. Asking for a library is off-topic.